# Xcode or native-react latches on to a wrong root directory to search for .ios.js file

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

```
2016-02-24 13:29:08.472 [fatal][tid:main] Cannot find entry file Examples/UIExplorer/UIExplorerApp.ios.js in any of the roots: ["~/ReactNativeApps/Starter"]
```

I am running from a new folder (`react-native/Examples/UIExplorer`) which was created by doing a git clone as described in the .md file of the Examples folder [link to Examples folder in github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer) in the github repository of native-react. The "root" in the error message happens to be another folder from which I had run successfully earlier instead of the one I am currently in where I executed `open UIExplorer.xcodeproj/` to start Xcode. The code can be found in [zipped folder in dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gd9kmp43cy8hskf/react-native.zip?dl=0)

Where should I look to see where the root is being defined. It appears to be an Xcode problem but there is no reference to the folder name in the build settings of Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this link [react-native-uiexplorer-wont-open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517769/react-native-uiexplorer-wont-open) the suggestion was that node was not updated so I went through the steps of cloning, etc. When I executed `npm start` I got an error that port 8081 was being used by another process. Then, executing `lsof -n -i4TCP:8081` displayed a number of processes using port 8081. When I killed the processes all my react-native problems magically disappeared.

It appears that terminating the process running the simulator does not terminate port 8081.